# Keyboard shortcut to move cursor to next Jupyter Notebook cell in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

Is it possible to move the cursor from one script cell to another using a keyboard shortcut using Visual Studio Code i.e. navigating between cells during editing?

I only found the possibility to *run* single cells but not the possibility of **moving only the cursor** to the next or to the previous script cell designated by `#%%`.

Comment: Does `Ctrl+DownArrow` do anything for you?

Comment: No, 'Ctrl+DownArrow' only scrolls down the page like when using the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

In a Jupyter Notebook editor, you can do this with the `Notebook: Focus Previous Cell Editor` and `Notebook: Focus Next Cell Editor` commands in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette). They are bound by default to the up and down arrow keys. If you want to customize the keybindings, their command IDs are `notebook.focusPreviousEditor` and `notebook.focusNextEditor`.

---

In an interactive Python file with code cells, you can do this using the `Jupyter: Go to Previous Cell` and `Jupyter: Go to Previous Cell` commands in the command palette. They are bound by default to <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> respectively. Their keyboard shortcut command IDs (if you want to customize your keyboard shortcuts) are `jupyter.gotoPrevCellInFile` and `jupyter.gotoNextCellInFile`.